# How does one say "toy airplane" in Japanese?

Tags: translation, meaning, word-choice, nuances

「飛行機のおもちゃ」と「おもちゃの飛行機」のどっちが正しい日本語？どっちも正しいんであれば、それぞれの使い方を説明してください。

伝えたいのはプラや木で出来ているおもちゃのことです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does one say “toy airplane” in Japanese?
>   プラや木で出来ているおもちゃ

普通は、「おもちゃの飛行機」って言うと思います。（「飛行機のおもちゃ」でもいいと思うんですが。）

<sub>「その箱、何が入ってるの？」って聞かれたら「小さい時に買ってもらったおもちゃの飛行機。」って言うと思いますけど、「**何のおもちゃ**が欲しい？」って聞かれたら「おもちゃの飛行機。」より「飛行機のおもちゃ。」って言うかな～と思います。</sub>

---

参考：

> おもちゃ Ⅰ-1
>   おもちゃのピストル a toy pistol [gun]
>   ([小学館プログレッシブ和英中辞典](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E7%8E%A9%E5%85%B7/#je-9056))

> toy (形)①
>   a toy car おもちゃの自動車
>   (ジーニアス英和辞典)

Comment: I agree with this. 「おもちゃの飛行機」 -> "A toy airplane (an airplane which is a toy)" そして逆に「飛行機のおもちゃ」-> "An airplane toy (A toy which is an airplane)" だからどっちでもいいと思います

Comment: でも、だれかにとって本物の飛行機はおもちゃみたいなものはどういうのかな？

Comment: @psosuna, you are talking about a "model plane".  My answer applies.

Comment: @ericfromabeno No, I really mean a real plane that someone might consider a "toy" (think spoiled rich kid)

Comment: `「おもちゃの飛行機」 -> "A toy airplane (an airplane which is a toy)" 「飛行機のおもちゃ」-> "An airplane toy (A toy which is an airplane)"` -- あそうそうそんな感じ～　 `a real plane that someone might consider a "toy"` -- それも「おもちゃの飛行機」って言いそう。「XXさんのおもちゃの飛行機」とか？

Comment: heh.  ah, the toys of the super-rich. ^_^  I wasn't even thinking in that direction. The wealthy do love their toys. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

if you want to convey the idea of a plastic or wooden model plane, rather than a toy store sort of plane for young children, neither of those choices is best (though おもちゃの飛行機 conveys the idea "a plane which is a toy"/"toy plane")

The best choice for your purposes is プラモデルの飛行機　for plastic model plane, and　木製模型飛行機 for wooden model plane.  It's important to note that these are not "toys", though some younger model builders might choose to use them as toys.